# PHP MYSQL PDO BLOB upload always empty zero bytes

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo

here is my upload code:

```
public function upload($id, $title, $year, $comments){
    $imagedata = fopen($_FILES['up_images']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

    $query = 'INSERT INTO uploads (uid, title, year, comments, image, image_name) VALUES (:uid, :title, :year, :comments, :image, :image_name)';
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':uid', $id);
    $statement->bindValue(':title', $title);
    $statement->bindValue(':year', $year);
    $statement->bindValue(':comments', $comments);
    $statement->bindValue(':image', $imagedata, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $statement->bindValue(':image_name', $_FILES['up_images']['name']);
    $statement->execute();

    // return $imagedata
    return $_FILES['up_images']['error'];
}
```

as you can see i returned ERROR and the actual IMAGE BUFFER

error = 0

returned raw buffer has all the raw image data

all my PARAMETERS pass and are successfully uploaded to the MYSQL db but the image data is NEVER passed: heres a screen of my PHPmyadmin

[image]

here is the table structure:

[image]

and here is my form:

```
<form action="digest.php" method="POST" id="up_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="up_acct" name="up_acct" type="text" placeholder="Your ID" value="<?php echo $_GET['up_acct']; ?>" />
<input id="up_title" name="up_title" type="text" placeholder=" Title" value="<?php echo $_GET['up_title']; ?>" />
<input id="up_year" name="up_year" type="text" placeholder="Year" value="<?php echo $_GET['up_year']; ?>" />
<input id="up_images" name="up_images" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif,.svg" />
<textarea id="up_comments" name="up_comments" placeholder="COMMENTS (optional)" cols="22" rows="5"><?php echo $_GET['up_comments']; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="up_submit" id="up_submit" value="UPLOAD">
```

the size of the image i am trying to upload is 80kb?

well below my php.ini settings.

my FILE DUMP shows all valid data including a valid temp directory and name and EVEN SIZE!

Am i missing some type of obscure configuration on mysql? php?

also - i cant store filepath name and retrieve from file system - part of a bigger project

Comment: Shouldn't you use `bindParam` for the `PDO::PARAM_LOB` instead of `bindValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) for `PDO::PARAM_LOB` -- `bindParam` (not `bindValue`) wants a file pointer, not the contents of the file.

```
$imagedata = fopen($_FILES['up_images']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$statement->bindParam(':image', $imagedata, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

As you mentioned, it isn't generally considered good practice to store images in the DB unless there is a very explicit reason to do so, and the downsides are well understood. If you aren't 100% sure it is necessary, it probably is not.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `bindParam` instead of `bindValue` for this scenario?

Comment: @Dan -- Anthony's note is relevant to you too